# Reset count based on the condition

Tags: t-sql, count, reset

SUPPOSE DATA AS FOLLOWING

[image]

I want the output to be like this:

I Wanted Extra column EventCount based on the event 'X'

If Event ='X' then 1 and increment if it's the same group.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Zaim Raza.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the sample data, expected results and what you've tried. (Linking to outside images makes your question useless to others if the images become inaccessible.) It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. `tsql` is not a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
create table #event
(
id int,
event varchar(10),
dates date
)

insert into #event
select  1,  'x',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  1,  'y',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  1,  'z',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  1,  'x',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  1,  'w',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  2,  'x',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  2,  'x',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  2,  'w',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  2,  'w',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  2,  'm',    '1/1/2016'  union all
select  2,  'x',    '1/1/2016'  

select *,row_number() over( order by id) as txts
into #evts
from #event

select * 
,(select sum(case when b.event='x' then 1 else 0 end ) from #evts b where b.txts <= a.txts and a.id = b.id) as outputs
from #evts a
```

Hope this solution helps you.